# How to Unit Test Method Calling IConfiguration.Get<T> extension

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

I have this very simple method that I need to unit test.

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static T GetValid<T>(this IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var obj = configuration.Get<T>();
        Validator.ValidateObject(obj, new ValidationContext(obj), true);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `configuration.Get<T>` is a static extension method and doesn't belong to `IConfiguration`. I can't change the implementation of that static method.

I'm thinking, perhaps the simplest way is to create a Memory Configuration Provider? But I don't know if I can create one without binding it to a web host.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The configuration module is independent of web host related features.

You should be able to create an in memory configuration to test against without the need to bind it to a web host.

Review the following example test

```
public class TestConfig {
    [Required]
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
    [Required] //<--NOTE THIS
    public string SomeOtherKey { get; set; }
}

//...

[Fact]
public void Should_Fail_Validation_For_Required_Key() {
    //Arrange
    var inMemorySettings = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Email:SomeKey", "value1"},
        //{"Email:SomeOtherKey", "value2"}, //Purposely omitted for required failure
        //...populate as needed for the test
    };

    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings)
        .Build();

    //Act
    Action act = () => configuration.GetSection("Email").GetValid<TestConfig>();

    //Assert
    ValidationException exception = Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(act);
    //...other assertions of validation results within exception object
}
```

This in my opinion would be coming close to an integration test, but ideally you are just using framework dependent features in order to isolate the testing of the extension method.

Comment: Thank you, this worked really well, and I can extend this nicely into a helper class so that all unit tests can make sure of this. 

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way of tackling the problem, avoiding Mock and lots of setup noise:

The InMemoryConfiguration *almost* gave me what I needed, so I extended it so that you can amend values after building the configuration (Situation I had I didn’t know all the mocked values at the time of building the Configuration)

https://gist.github.com/martinsmith1968/9567de76d2bbe537af05d76eb39b1162

Unit test at the bottom shows usage

Answer (score 0):

Most of mocking libraries(Moq, FakeItEasy, etc) can't mock extension methods.

So, you have to 'fill' your IConfiguration in a way that a `IConfiguration.Get<T>` returns an instance of T. Nkoski answer works for a **lot** of scenarios, but not if you **need** to test a code that calls `IConfiguration.Get<T>` you can use the example bellow:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Xunit;

public class TestClass {
    public class Movie
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Rating { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Stars { get; set; } //it works with collections
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var movie = new Movie { 
            Name = "Some Movie",
            Rating = 9, 
            Stars = new List<string>{"Some actress", "Some actor"}
        };

        var movieAsJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(movie));
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream(movieAsJson))
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();
            var movieFromConfig = config.Get<Movie>();
            //var sut = new SomeService(config).SomeMethodThatCallsConfig.Get<Movie>()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IConfiguration mock = new MockConfiguration();
        var simpleObject = mock.GetValid<SimpleObject>();
        Assert.AreEqual(simpleObject.MyConfigStr, "123");
    }
}

public class SimpleObject
{
    public string MyConfigStr { get; set; }
}


public class MockConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    public IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key)
    {
        return new MockConfigurationSection()
        {
            Value = "123"
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren()
    {
        var configurationSections = new List<IConfigurationSection>()
        {
            new MockConfigurationSection()
            {
                Value = "MyConfigStr"
            }
        };
        return configurationSections;
    }

    public Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken GetReloadToken()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MockConfigurationSection : IConfigurationSection
{
    public IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren()
    {
        return new List<IConfigurationSection>();
    }

    public IChangeToken GetReloadToken()
    {
        return new MockChangeToken();
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Key { get; }
    public string Path { get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MockChangeToken : IChangeToken
{
    public IDisposable RegisterChangeCallback(Action<object> callback, object state)
    {
        return new MockDisposable();
    }

    public bool HasChanged { get; }
    public bool ActiveChangeCallbacks { get; }
}

public class MockDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

created a mock for IConfiguration and mimic the behaviour of ConfigBinder

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
```

added these two namespace for it compile

Comment: That's my first attempt, but nope. Get is a static extension method part of ConfigurationBinder, not part of IConfiguration. Moq is thus not helping me.